# Read XML-File correctly using XmlReader using C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, xmlreader

I'm writing a short program which displays me all my To Do's. I got 2 tabs. 1 Tab is for create a new To Do and the other tab is for displaying me the details of every To Do I selected. So I have to save the created To Do's in a xml file. For this I am using DataTable and DataSet and it works fine. Here my code:

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\save.xml"))
            {
                dataset.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\save.xml");

                dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(txt_Name.Text, combox_Priority.Text, txt_Beginn.Text, txt_EndSoll.Text, txt_EndIst.Text, txt_Bemerkungen.Text);
                dataset.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\save.xml");
            }

            else
            {
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                datatable.TableName = "SaveInput";

                DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
                DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Priority");
                DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("StartDate");
                DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("EndDateSoll");
                DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("EndDateIst");
                DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("Comment");

                datatable.Columns.Add(dc1);
                datatable.Columns.Add(dc2);
                datatable.Columns.Add(dc3);
                datatable.Columns.Add(dc4);
                datatable.Columns.Add(dc5);
                datatable.Columns.Add(dc6);

                datatable.Rows.Add(txt_Name.Text, combox_Priority.Text, txt_Beginn.Text, txt_EndSoll.Text, txt_EndIst.Text, txt_Bemerkungen.Text);

                DataSet dataset2 = new DataSet();

                dataset2.Tables.Add(datatable);
                dataset2.DataSetName = "iToDo";

                dataset2.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\save.xml");
            }

            XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\save.xml");
            XmlNodeType nodetype;

            while (xmlreader.Read())
            {
                nodetype = xmlreader.NodeType;

                if (nodetype == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (xmlreader.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        combox_Name2.Items.Add(xmlreader.Value);
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "Priority")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "StartDate")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "EndDateSoll")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "EndDateIst")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "Comment")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                    }
                }
            }

            xmlreader.Close();
        }
```

My problem now is: I want that everytime I select a "To-Do" I created it should display me the correct details. So I was working with `SelectedIndexChanged`. I also used

```
if (combox_Name2.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {

            }
```

But I think I didn't code it correctly because the details does not display. Can someone give me a hint? I was editing my code the whole afternoon but for a beginner it is really difficult if you don't know where you made an error. :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [xml serializer](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization). Datatables are a pain to work with, so you could create a "To-Do" class and display the properties of this class after clicking on the corresponding identifier (lets say name) in your combobox.

The serialization might not be the problem here, it most likely got more to do with what you try to display in your combobox, and how that is linked to the rows of your datasets...

**Edit:** I have two possible solutions. They are both buggy and ugly, but its the best one can do within the limits of your implementation. Number one:

Make your dataset accessible by all methods in your class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private DataSet dataset;
    private DataTable datatable;

    public Form1()
    {
```

You can then (after initializing it, and making sure its got a table in it, all minor adjustments to your class) do the following in your combobox Eventhandler:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            DataTable tempTable = dataset.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in tempTable.Rows)
            {
                if (row[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    label1.Text = row[1].ToString();
                    label2.Text = row[2].ToString();
                    label3.Text = row[3].ToString();
                    label4.Text = row[4].ToString();
                    label5.Text = row[5].ToString();
                    label6.Text = row[6].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

I filled labels with the text, but im pretty sure you can figure out how to fill some other controls as well ;) The second solution is even messier, but it requires no adjustments to your existing code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1) {
            XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\save.xml");
            XmlNodeType nodetype;
            bool xmlReaderArmed = false;
            while (xmlreader.Read())
            {
                nodetype = xmlreader.NodeType;

                if (nodetype == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (xmlreader.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        if (xmlreader.Value == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) {
                            label1.Text = xmlreader.Value;
                            xmlReaderArmed = true; 
                        }
                    }
                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "Priority" && xmlReaderArmed)
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        label2.Text = xmlreader.Value;

                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "StartDate" && xmlReaderArmed)
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        label3.Text = xmlreader.Value;
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "EndDateSoll" && xmlReaderArmed)
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        label4.Text = xmlreader.Value;
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "EndDateIst" && xmlReaderArmed)
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        label5.Text = xmlreader.Value;
                    }

                    else if (xmlreader.Name == "Comment" && xmlReaderArmed)
                    {
                        xmlreader.Read();
                        label6.Text = xmlreader.Value;
                        xmlReaderArmed = false;
                    }



                }
            }

            xmlreader.Close();
        }
```

I STILL strongly suggest you rework your solution. The entire thing is very unstable, and very hard to maintain. Read up some tutorials about object orientated programming and have a look at some other peoples solutions similar to yours, such as an address book implementation maybe :) Good luck on your endeavours!

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. I will look at it but is there no way with DataTable and DataSet? Because I'm a newbie and I have learnt DataTable and DataSet in the last two days so I really want to go on in this way if you understand :)

Comment: Actually, like i said, you really shouldnt use datatable and so forth. But ill try to get something done with your code in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, so I am guessing this:

```
// Associate the event-handling method with the SelectedIndexChanged event. 
combox_Name2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(Combox_Name2_SelectedIndexChanged);

// The event-handling method
private void Combox_Name2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your work here
}
```